# Escape quotes in a string with backslash

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I have a string: `" \" "`. I would like to escape all unescaped double-quotes, i.e. add a backslash before `"` if it's note there.

```
input = '" \\" "'
input.replace(???) == '\\" \\" \\"'
```

I've tried

```
input.replace(/(?!\\)"/g, '\\"')
```

It escapes second backslash twice (`'\" \\" \"'`) for the reason I don't understand.

I've figured out

```
(' ' + input).replace(/([^\\])"/g, '$1\\"').slice(1)
```

But it looks ugly. It has to be a better way.

---

**Update:**

One more test case:

```
>> input = '" \\" \\\\" \\\\\\"'
-> '" \" \\" \\\"'
>> input.replace(???)
-> '\" \" \\\" \\\"'
```

None of my regular expressions can handle it.

Comment: JS doesn't support lookbehinds, but I'm trying to emulate them. `[^\]` doesn't compile (throws SyntaxError).

Comment: Ah sorry, I guess, it's me who got confused then ;) Right, ``\`` is also the escape characters inside an expression. My apologies... deleted my comment as it does not make sense at all...

Comment: Anyways, the backslash is escaped because although `\"` does not match, `"` does. As your expression is not anchored, every position/character is tried to match.

Answer (score 4):

What I have is scarcely better, but it does handle escaped backslashes too:

```
>>> var v= 'a\\"b'
>>> v
"a\"b"
>>> v.replace(/(\\*)(")/g, function(x) { var l = x.length; return (l % 2) ? x : x.substring(0,l-1) + '\\"' } )
"a\\"b"
>>> var v= 'a\\\\"b'
>>> v
"a\\"b"
>>> v.replace(/(\\*)(")/g, function(x) { var l = x.length; return (l % 2) ? x : x.substring(0,l-1) + '\\"' } )
"a\\"b"
```

If there are an *odd* number of slashes before a quote (1, 3, 5), the quote is already escaped; an even number (including zero), in needs escaping.

Made all the harder to read by the necessary of escaping the slashes *in input* and by the inability of the colorizer to understand the regexp expression...

Of course, you probably shouldn't even be doing this.  If you have a raw string and you need something you can pass to (e.g.) `eval`, consider `$.toJSON`.

Comment: It should be `function(x, y) {var l = y.length;`.

Comment: No, it should be `function(all, backslashes, quote) {return backslashes.length % 2 ? all : backslashes + '\\' + quote}`. Thanks for the tip anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
var arf = input.replace(/(^|[^\\])"/g, '$1\\"');
```

It says, replace a quote, when preceded by beginning-of-string or anything-other-than-backslash, with backslash followed by quote.

Comment: It does what I originally asked, but it doesn't handle the test case that I just added.

Comment: It answers your question, exactly, so you changed the question. I get it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String(str).replace(/[\\"']/g, "\\$&")
   .replace(/[\r\n\u2028\u2029]/g,
   function (x) {
     switch (x) {
     case '\n': return "\\n";
     case '\r': return "\\r";
     case '\u2028': return "\\u2028";
     case '\u2029': return "\\u2029";
     }
   })
```

The `String` call ensures that the input is a valid string.

The first replace will handle quotes and backslashes.  The second handles embedded line terminators.

If you want to deal with an already quoted string, you can change the first replace to this:

```
'"' + String(str).replace(/^"|"$/g, "").replace(/[\\"]/g, "\\$&") + '"'
```

to unquote and requote.

Comment: Taken original input, your code produces `'\" \\\" \"'` instead of `'\" \" \"'`.