# Check to see if string contains quotes, and if it does, place an escape '\' before

Tags: javascript

I need to parse strings for single and double quotes, and if the string does contain them, I need to add an escape slash before.  What would be the most efficient way? Is there a way to use a regex to check this through a function?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382115/escape-quotes-in-a-string-with-backslash

Comment: Damn, I thought I did a more thorough job of searching...Sorry about that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely!

```
​var str = 'abcd"\'efg"hij';

alert(str.replace(/(\"|\')/g, '\\$1'));​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ // alerts abcd\"\'efg\"hi
```

Answer (score 2):

Could be something like that:

```
str.replace(/["']/g,"\\$&");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str.replace(/(\"|\')/g, "\\$1");
```

Comment: Why are you using character classes like that?